# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: hibernate, annotations, sqlexception

Could someone help me understand that why am I getting the following error when I am trying to persist **ServiceProvider** entity?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`springmvc/businesslocation`, CONSTRAINT `FK5CB747B5A26ED80E` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `state` (`id`))
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1129)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:681)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1368)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1283)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
 at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:72)
 at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2163)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2643)
 at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:511)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:503)
 at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:218)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:296)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:242)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:219)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:539)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:527)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:642)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:373)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:639)
 at com.inception.dao.ServiceProviderDAOImpl.save(ServiceProviderDAOImpl.java:23)
 at com.inception.service.ServiceProviderServiceImpl.addServiceProvider(ServiceProviderServiceImpl.java:21)
 at com.inception.web.RegisterServiceProviderController.processFinish(RegisterServiceProviderController.java:68)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController.validatePagesAndFinish(AbstractWizardFormController.java:642)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController.processFormSubmission(AbstractWizardFormController.java:492)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

The situation is like this: **a ServiceProvider has a List of BusinessLocation and a State has a list of BusinessLocation**.

Following annotated classes that I want to be persisted:
**ServiceProvider.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class ServiceProvider implements Serializable{

 private Long id; 
 private Set<BusinessLocation> businessLocations = new HashSet<BusinessLocation>();

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="serviceProvider", targetEntity=BusinessLocation.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 public Set<BusinessLocation> getBusinessLocations() {
  return businessLocations;
 }

 public void setBusinessLocations(Set<BusinessLocation> businessLocations) {
  this.businessLocations = businessLocations;
 }

}
```

**BusinessLocation,java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class BusinessLocation implements Serializable{

 private Long id;
 private String address;
 private String city;
 private State state;
 private String pincode;
 private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

 public BusinessLocation() {  
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getAddress() {
  return address;
 }
 public void setAddress(String address) {
  this.address = address;
 }
 public String getCity() {
  return city;
 }
 public void setCity(String city) {
  this.city = city;
 }

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="state_id")
 public State getState() {
  return state;
 }
 public void setState(State state) {
  this.state = state;
 } 
 public void setPincode(String pincode) {
  this.pincode = pincode;
 }

 public String getPincode() {
  return pincode;
 }

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="serviceProvider_id")
 public ServiceProvider getServiceProvider() {
  return serviceProvider;
 }
 public void setServiceProvider(ServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
  this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
 }
}
```

**State.java**

```
@Entity
public class State implements Serializable {

 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private List<BusinessLocation> businessLocations;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue 
 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }


 @OneToMany(mappedBy="state", targetEntity=BusinessLocation.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 public List<BusinessLocation> getBusinessLocations() {
  return businessLocations;
 }
 public void setBusinessLocations(List<BusinessLocation> businessLocations) {
  this.businessLocations = businessLocations;
 } 

}
```

Looking forward to someone waking me up of the blunder I might be commiting here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I think this error was being created coz I was ignorantly trying to override the IDs created by Hibernate in the path set for select tag in my views.

Here is the code for my service and dao class:
**ServiceProviderServiceImpl**

```
@Transactional
public class ServiceProviderServiceImpl implements ServiceProviderService{

    private ServiceProviderDAO serviceProviderDAO;
    public void setServiceProviderDAO(ServiceProviderDAO serviceProviderDAO) {
        this.serviceProviderDAO = serviceProviderDAO;
    }

    public void addServiceProvider(ServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        serviceProviderDAO.save(serviceProvider);
        for(BusinessLocation businessLocation: serviceProvider.getBusinessLocations()) {
            businessLocation.setServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            serviceProviderDAO.save(businessLocation);
        }

    }

}
```

**ServiceProviderDAOImpl** 
    public class ServiceProviderDAOImpl implements ServiceProviderDAO{

```
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void save(ServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(serviceProvider);        
    }

    public void save(BusinessLocation businessLocation) {
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(businessLocation);       
    }

}
```

But once I had the this problem resolved I started having the error below:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.inception.domain.State; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.inception.domain.State
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:634)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:378)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:639)
   at com.inception.dao.ServiceProviderDAOImpl.save(ServiceProviderDAOImpl.java:23)
   at com.inception.service.ServiceProviderServiceImpl.addServiceProvider(ServiceProviderServiceImpl.java:21)
   at com.inception.web.RegisterServiceProviderController.processFinish(RegisterServiceProviderController.java:68)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController.validatePagesAndFinish(AbstractWizardFormController.java:642)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractWizardFormController.processFormSubmission(AbstractWizardFormController.java:492)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.inception.domain.State
   at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:219)
   at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:397)
   at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:242)
   at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.findDirty(TypeFactory.java:596)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3128)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:478)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:204)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:127)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1004)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.flushIfNecessary(HibernateAccessor.java:390)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
   ... 27 more
```

I got it resolved by setting cascade property to (**cascade=CascadeType.ALL**) as below in the entity **BusinessLocation.java**.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="state_id")
public State getState() {
    return state;
}
```

Many thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The mappings look correct and it would have been interesting to show the code where you actually try to persist the `ServiceProvider` instance.

In particular, I would pay a special attention on the various bidirectional associations to make sure you set "the link on both sides" correctly before to persist.

You might actually want to create link management methods for this, for example in `ServiceProvider`:

```
@Entity
public class ServiceProvider implements Serializable{
    private Long id; 
    private Set<BusinessLocation> businessLocations = new HashSet<BusinessLocation>();

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
      return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="serviceProvider", targetEntity=BusinessLocation.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<BusinessLocation> getBusinessLocations() {
      return businessLocations;
    }

    public void setBusinessLocations(Set<BusinessLocation> businessLocations) {
      this.businessLocations = businessLocations;
    }

    public void addToBusinessLocations(BusinessLocation businessLocation) {
      this.getBusinessLocations().add(businessLocation);
      businessLocation.setServiceProvider(this);
    }

    public void removeFromBusinessLocations(BusinessLocation businessLocation) {
      this.getBusinessLocations().remove(businessLocation);
      businessLocation.setServiceProvider(null);
    }        
}
```

Same thing in `State`.

Not setting both sides of the links correctly might be the cause of the problem.